# Terminology of functions that is convex in certain arguments

Tags: convex-analysis, terminology

What's the terminology indicating functions that is convex in certain arguments, for example,
$f(x, \cdot)$ is convex for all $x$?

Comment: Maybe convex with respect to $x$?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thanks :) Do you think that it is also called to be "partially convex"?
Actually I've used the term and (probably) seen it in some papers, but I'm not sure that it's widely used.

Comment: I haven't seen this definition before but unless you define it I don't see a reason not to use it.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thank you for your advice!